# Why do states with $m_1 + m_2$ have to vanish in the Clebsch-Gordon expansion of combined states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, quantum-spin

I'm  currently studying QM and more specifically addition of spin angular momentum. I'm using the handbook from Griffiths.

A combined state $|s m \rangle$ can be written using Clebsch-Gordon coefficients as:

$$ |s m \rangle = \sum_{m_1+m_2=m}C^{s_1 s_2 s}_{m_1 m_2 m}|s_1 s_2 m_1 m_2 \rangle $$

It is then argued that only composite states which have $m_1+m_2=m$ are included in the sum, or equivalently: the CG-coefficients vanish if $m_1+m_2 \neq m$. Griffiths explains this by saying this that the $z$-components add.

But let's look at the combined state $|1 0 \rangle$. Why can't the states $|\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2} \rangle$ and $|\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{2} \rangle$ be included in the sum. the first one has a spin $z$-component of $1$ and the second of $-1$, and they just add to $0$, in agreement with the total $z$-spin of the combined state.

So why is there a problem? Why can't these states be included?

Comment: As you say, independently, those are eigenstates of $J_z$. But a linear combination of them will never be an eigenstate of $J_z$.

Comment: "the first one has a spin z-component of 1 and the second of −1, and they just add to 0." That's not how addition of angular momentum works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a proof (first I act $\hat{J}_z$ on the right, and second I act it on the left):
$$
\langle sm|\hat{J}_z|s_1s_2m_1m_2\rangle=\hbar(m_1+m_2)\langle sm|s_1s_2m_1m_2\rangle=\hbar m\langle sm|s_1s_2m_1m_2\rangle
$$
So if $m_1+m_2\neq m$ then $\langle sm|s_1s_2m_1m_2\rangle$ has to be zero.

Conceptually... if two states are eigenstates of any Hermetian operator with different eigenvalues they have to be orthogonal. This is an immediate consequence of the spectral theorem.

A bit speculative, but it feels like you're confusing "adding angular momenta" in the sense of combining two systems into one combined wavefunction like:
$$
\left|\frac{1}{2},m_1\right\rangle \otimes\left|\frac{1}{2},m_2\right\rangle =\left|\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}m_1m_2\right\rangle 
$$
versus adding two wavefunctions to form a linear combination like:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\left|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle+\left|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle\right)
$$